# Retrofit2 GsonConverter Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, generics, gson, retrofit2

I met some problem.
I'm trying to get data from server like this..

```
{
"Message": "",
"StatusCode": 0,
"Payload": [
    [

        {

        },
        {

        }
    ],
    [
        {

        },
        {

        }
    ]
]
```

}

My BaseResponse is...

```
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String Message;

@SerializedName("StatusCode")
@Expose
private int StatusCode;

@SerializedName("Payload")
@Expose
private T Payload;

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public int getStatusCode() {
    return StatusCode;
}

public T getPayload() {
    return Payload;
}
```

My my retrofit interface is...

```
 @Multipart
@POST(APIServer.Tstgen.POST)
Observable<BaseResponse<List<List<MoneyResponse>>>> getMoneyMainResult(
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap
);
```

I think that everything is OK but...
it alway get wrong when Gson converting...

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

what's wrong about my code?

Comment: make payload class into List

Comment: @AllenHuang : the issue is that for 'Payload' it is expecting `Object` but api is returning `Array`. So either you need to make change in the model class or in API response. If you are sure that api will return `Array` everytime, you should make `PayLoad` to `Array<T>` rahter than `T`.

Comment: you can use www.jsonschema2pojo.com

Comment: looks like your actual JSON is not what you expect it to be

Answer (score 1):

change into response class and add your payload class into list.

```
 @SerializedName("Payload")
 private List<Payload> payloadList;
```

make getter setter method

Comment: but...not all the response is array...
some of the response is object

Comment: that time make key are different and create object for getter setter

Answer (score 0):

Set Payload into List likebelow

```
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String Message;

@SerializedName("StatusCode")
@Expose
private int StatusCode;

@SerializedName("Payload")
@Expose
private List<Payload> Payload;

public String getMessage() {
return Message;
}

public int getStatusCode() {
return StatusCode;
}

public List<Payload> getPayload() {
return Payload;
}

 public  setPayload(List<Payload> payload) {
 this.payload=payload;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change type `Payload` field in your **Base Repository** like below:

```
@SerializedName("Payload")
@Expose
private List<List<T>> Payload;
```

for more understanding about retrofit documentation, this **[Link](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)** is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String Message;

@SerializedName("StatusCode")
@Expose
private int StatusCode;

@SerializedName("Payload")
@Expose
private Object Payload;

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public int getStatusCode() {
    return StatusCode;
}

public T getPayload() {
    return Payload;
}
```

try using Object instead of generic.
As Object is super type of all the types you can then type cast it.

Answer (score 0):

apart from the responses given above..also re-check your web service URL...this error also comes due to incorrect URL